# How to remove empty rows in an exported xlsx file using JRXlsxExporter?

Tags: java, report, xlsx

When I'm exporting an xlsx file using JRXlsxExporter, a empty row appears after some results.
I saw that the XlsReportConfiguration has a static property PROPERTY_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, and his default boolean value is false.

I tried to change the value but I can't.

Someone can help me to solve this situation?

follow some part of my code:

`final JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();`

`XlsxReportConfiguration xlsxReportConfiguration = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();`
`exporter.setConfiguration(xlsxReportConfiguration);`

`exporter.exportReport();`

[Update]
Finally I resolved this. 
I got change the value using a cast like this

`((AbstractXlsReportConfiguration)xlsxReportConfiguration).setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(Boolean.TRUE);`

before to set configuration of exporter.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to delete blank columns:

```
// The path to the documents directory.
string dataDir = RunExamples.GetDataDir(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

// Open an existing excel file.
Workbook wb = new Workbook(dataDir+ "SampleInput.xlsx");

// Create a Worksheets object with reference to
// The sheets of the Workbook.
WorksheetCollection sheets = wb.Worksheets;

// Get first Worksheet from WorksheetCollection
Worksheet sheet = sheets[0];

// Delete the Blank Rows from the worksheet
sheet.Cells.DeleteBlankRows();

// Save the excel file.
wb.Save(dataDir+ "mybook.out.xlsx");
```

This is to delete empty rows:

```
// The path to the documents directory.
string dataDir = RunExamples.GetDataDir(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
// Open an existing excel file.
Workbook wb = new Workbook(dataDir+ "SampleInput.xlsx");
// Create a Worksheets object with reference to
// The sheets of the Workbook.
WorksheetCollection sheets = wb.Worksheets;
// Get first Worksheet from WorksheetCollection
Worksheet sheet = sheets[0];
// Delete the Blank Rows from the worksheet
sheet.Cells.DeleteBlankRows();
// Save the excel file.
wb.Save(dataDir+ "mybook.out.xlsx");
```

Also try this:

> 1) Set param as mentioned before:
>   exporterXLS.setParameter
>   (JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS,Boolean.TRUE);
>
> 2) Making the heigh of all fields exactly the same as the band they
>   are located on
>
> 3) Setting the property "Stretch Type" for all fields on the band to
>   the value "Relative to Band Height" for all fields on the band.

Comment: I am unsure of the effectiveness for your issue but this does the trick for me when I run into the issue you have.

Comment: >1) Set param as mentioned before: exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
>
>
>
>2) Making the heigh of all fields exactly the same as the band they are >located on
>
> 
>
>3) Setting the property "Stretch Type" for all fields on the band to the value >"Relative to Band Height" for all fields on the band.

Comment: thanks Two_Years_Experience =D I changed the propertie default boolean value using a cast in xlsxReportConfiguration object to acess the method  setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows of AbstractXlsReportConfiguration class, and this solve my problem. But I will try your advice =D